# appcompat v7 23, actionbars, transparency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

I think I went all over SO for the answer. I think I  am being trolled by Android L... Seems no matter what I do that actionbar's background still defaults to `colorPrimary`

the **layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          android:id="@+id/dl_main"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.farmdog.farmdog.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        <!--layout_behavior="TransparentScrollingViewBehavior"/>-->

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"-->
                <!--app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">-->
                <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
                <!--app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"-->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
........
```

and **styles.xml (v21)**

```
 <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <!-- colorPrimaryDark wont work on API level < 21 -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/mainBkgndHard</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/appTextColor</item>
            <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
            <!--<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>          hmmm, primaryColor expands on the statusbar now...-->
            <!-- attempt taking actionbar shadow away -->
            <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <!-- the following line breaks the build-->
            <!--<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>-->
            <!-- attempt drawing underneath the actionbar - all fail as of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.'-->
            <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <!--<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">-->
            <!--<item name="android:background">@color/colorActionBar</item>-->
            <!--<item name="background">@color/colorActionBar</item>-->
            <!--<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
            <!--<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
        <!--</style>-->



        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
            <item name="android:background">@color/colorActionBar</item>
            <!--For compatibility-->
            <item name="background">@color/colorActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        </style>


    </resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are doing it in the wrong way.I mean, the following **Toolbar** Hasn't any **PrimaryColor** or even **Background:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"-->
                <!--app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">-->
                <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
                <!--app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"-->
```

So, this will works on (v21) versions only without any background or `PrimaryColor`.and as you can see, **Toolbar** is going to be like your `Activity Theme` which that has:

```
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

**With:**

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

---

And, if you don't set any background color or **PrimaryColor**, because of:

```
 Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

and your `Toolbar`, ***it has to be like that***:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Otherwise, **it should crashed(i guess, not sure) because you have a Theme with `DarkActionBar` and one Toolbar with no background.**

I think this is the problem!

**Edit:**

For completing the answer, since this code was simple anyway, i'll add it here:

Add this also in your `AppBarLayout`:

```
android:theme
```

Comment: You may want to change some bits before ticking it green:
It was the `AppBarLayout` the one in need of a  `android:colorPrimary` / `colorPrimary`. `(android:)background` has no effect whatsoever in this case, and nothing going to crash :)

Comment: Oh, i was saying your problem, that appbarlayout is simple, you can suggest an edit which worked for you,BTW.goodluck

Comment: I have added `android:colorPrimary` and `android:colorPrimary` properties inside the  `<AppBarLayout/>` element

Comment: Added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Mohsen answer, I did the following:

- Defined a theme named AppTheme with parent Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

  ```
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  ```
- In AndroidManifest.xml, I assigned **AppTheme** as the android:theme

  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
- Created another theme for AppBarLayout named CollapsingToolbarTheme with parent Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

  ```
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  ```
- Finally, I assigned the new **CollapsingToolbarTheme** as the theme of AppBarLayout

  android:theme="@style/CollapsingToolbarTheme"